# Error al tratar de desencriptar con CryptoJs: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript

Me está dando el error que mencioné antes al tratar de desencriptar el token que se encuentra en el json. Ya intenté con stringify y tampoco.

al igual con: *JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(token_by)) pero según leí es una mala práctica

```js
let token_by = {'token_express': 'token...'}

let decryptedToken = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(JSON.parse(token_by).token_express, key);

    let decryptedData = JSON.parse(decryptedToken.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Esto ya es un objeto, no te hace falta hacer el JSON.parse():  `{'token_express': 'token...'}`

Comment: Tal como te comentan, el token no esta en una cadena JSON, está en un objeto. OBJETO !== JSON. Recuerda que JSON es un formato de cadena, es decir, una cadena de texto con un formato particular, que se asemeja a un Objeto de JavaScript. En tu caso, no hace falta usar `JSON.parse` porque la variable `token_by` no es una cadena, sino un Objeto. Puedes comprobar esto haciendo `console.log(typeof token_by);`. Saludos